# Return key in process

Tags: process

The code was run as:

```
u = subprocess.Popen(['process','abc','def','','ghi','jkl'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It doesn't work below due to an error occurred:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect), it is far more well-suited for this tasks (actually, it *is* a tool built for these kind of tasks).

You can also browse througn [examples](http://pexpect.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pexpect/trunk/pexpect/examples/) and see what its usage looks like.

Comment: +1, pexpect is hands-down the best way to control interactive processes.